# Google Maps MarkerClusterer doesn't reflect the correct number of markers

Tags: google-maps, numbers, markerclusterer

I've created a map that uses the MarkerClusterer library. It seems to work but there are a couple of issues.

First, it seems that the number of markers represented by the cluster is sometimes a bit off - ie, sometimes a cluster will say it has 24 markers, but when you click on it, 40 markers show in the window.

Second, once you zoom out a few levels, the numbers get crazy - we've only got 4k+ markers and I get clusters with 12k+ numbers on them.

I've got no idea how how to move forward. Would love some help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a MCVE? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) It would greatly help us answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have an event listener that calls showMarkers when the map is idle.  That function adds all the markers to the clusterer every time the idle event fires (so you end up with multiple copies of each marker).  You probably want addListenerOnce instead of addListener.

Another option would be to clear out the markers in the clusterer before adding them all back in again, but since you seem to only need to add a fixed set of markers to the clusterer one time, that would probably not be the best option.

Comment: Actually, addListenerOnce works, but if you zoom, the markers within the new bounds aren't added -

Comment: still stumped... i've tried clearing the clusterer then re-adding the markers but can't get it to work...

Comment: Your link in your question no longer works (I get 404).  One thought without looking at the code, change your code to load all the markers rather than only those in view and use addListenerOnce.  The other option would be to make clearing out the clusterer work, but you have to be careful with that as you don't want multiple requests active at the same time, can't help you with that without seeing yuor existing code.

Comment: sorry - tinkering with multiple - here's the link: [link](http://www.tantomedia.com/artofneighboring/maptest_main/maptest/map_viewport_and_clusterer.html) - this works fine if I load all markers, but we've got many and will have more - would be great to get this working via loading only markers in viewport...

Comment: I managed to clear out the marker array before it's reloaded, which seems to be giving the correct numbers, but I haven't figured out how to clear the clusters, then reload.

Comment: The [MarkerClustererPlus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/docs/reference.html) has a clearMarkers() method, are you using that?  Note your map doesn't work (displays a grey box rather than a map), if I don't allow it to access my location.

Comment: I've tried clearMarkers() just after I clear the marker array but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  Thanx for the heads' up on the location issue.  Really appreciate your input.

Comment: The geolocation failing still results in a grey box, javascript is case sensitive, Denver and denver are different (Uncaught ReferenceError: denver is not defined).  After that I get one other javascript error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getNorthEast' of undefined", probably because the map isn't initialized.  I don't see clearMarkers on your live map.  I do see you are creating a new MarkerClusterer everytime you download markers, I would suggest just creating it once (in your initialize function), then clearing it out and reloading it in your showMarkers function.

Comment: The map's now loaded into a Joomla install at [link](http://www.artofneighboring.com/joomla/index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=1&Itemid=106).  Should work without allowing your location.  I'm not sure how to create markers before I load them - would I also need to load markers in my initialize function?  Then clear them out at the end of the function?

Comment: Still doesn't work if I deny geolocation.  It does work if I submit Denver, Co in the "Center on a different address" box and submit it.